launch vm and its LVM cinder volumes on same host
I have an OpenStack Antelope version installed via Kolla-Ansible, and I have several compute hosts with LVM volume types. When I create an instance using an LVM volume, I expect both the volume and the instance create on the same host. However, they end up on different hosts. For example, the volume is located on d13-compute43@localA#localA, whereas the instance is on d13-compute51
